# How to make method wait the result from listener before return value?

Tags: java, android

I have a method which need to return from a value on another background method. The problem is the line return always run before the background method return the data.

Please look the code below,  **line 8** always run before **line 5**.
How can I handle this case ?

```
 public String methodAbc(){
      int result = 0;
      doSomeWorkWithCallBack(new ResultListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFinish(int data)){
               result = data; //line 5
           }
      }
      return result; // line 8
    }
```

Comment: This is not the best approach to stop your main thread until some asynchronous background task performed its work. You should look for other better options such as `AsynTask` or `Handler`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using a callback, your `methodAbc()` shouldn't returns the result.

So instead of doing:

```
public void methodExpectingResult(){
    int result = methodAbc();
    // do something with the result
}
```

You can do:

```
public void methodExpectingResult(){
    methodAbc();
    // do nothing
}

public void methodAbc() {
    int result = 0;
    doSomeWorkWithCallBack(new ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish(int data) {
            onMethodAbcReturn(data);
        }
    });

}

private void onMethodAbcReturn(int data) {
    // do something with the result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is threaded you shouldn't be having that issue.  If this is threaded then it would be best to wrap this in a custom AsyncTask.

```
class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Result> {
    @Override
    protected Result doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Result result = new Result();
        // do some work
        // don't do anything in here that works on the UI :: this is a asynchronous call
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // do something with result
    }
}
```